How would humans interact with a super intelligence?
I am investigating this question partly for the purpose of constructing my first short story, partly for conceiving of a protocol which can actually be used to interface with superintelligences, whether cosmic entities or future advanced AIs. In any case, since the answer to my question will impact the world in my short science fiction story I'm asking this question here rather than on machine learning or philosophy stack exchange. I also think I'll get the most creative answers.
Consider an interaction between a group of humans Gottfried, Isaac, and Emmy, and a mysterious hyperintelligent entity (HE) which communicates in bits. The exact nature of this entity's mind is presently unknown, however using information theory and an understanding of coding, our group has been able to decode the bitstream which yields a stream of text in natural human language, specifically Latin, which is coherent. As a verification of this being's intelligence, our team asked this intelligence for a machine-verifiable proof of the Riemmann hypothesis in the lean programming language. After running the proof on Ada's 2015 Macbook Air, the proof was found to be correct, although exhibiting a form of mathematical reasoning which was unfamiliar even to Gottfried. The conclusion of this interaction is that the entity is a hyperintelligent entity whose level of insight excels even the intuitions of humanity's greatest minds.
The protagonists soon understand that they have an opportunity for limitless discovery, if only they could determine how to tap into the vast abilities of this intelligence. My question is: what kind of protocol might they conceive of to engage with this intellect in the most effective and fruitful way? I can imagine this scenario in terms of a bunch of precocious 12 year olds sitting before Isaac Newton and trying to figure out what to ask him that will give them maximal insight. By asking bad questions, they will not learn.
So my question is, what are some ideas, possibly based on precedents in human times, for how the protagonists learn to probe into the language of the entity, perhaps in a way that elevates them closer to the way it processes rather than lowering it to the level at which they process?

Establishing a protocol is setting up guidelines on how to interact with a (extra-dimensional-terrestial-whatever) being. It seems that this step is already done. The bit stream is deciphered, the language is determined, even a first question was asked and an answer given... why not just continue this way? I can't see your worldbuilding problem right now. -- The last paragraph implies that you would like to know how your story should progress... this also would not be a worldbuilding question.

"trying to figure out what to ask him that will give them maximal insight" But why? Are they somehow limited in the number of questions they can ask? If not, then why wouldn't they just take a spray-and-pray approach - asking lots of questions? Assuming the answers are honest and accurate, then even a "no, that question doesn't make sense" response would still have value by guiding how to frame further questions.

"Probe into the language of this entity"? What does this mean? The question says that entity writes in Latin. We know the Latin language in considerable depth. Several variants of the Latin language, to be more precise. There is not much we could possibly learn about the Latin language. (Well, lots of details are still waiting to be learned, for example what exactly did the Romans say at the dining table. But I don't believe that this entity knows them, unless it was present in the times of the Romans.)

Thank you all for your ideas. For me, its hard to know the difference between worldbuilding versus storytelling. In any case, i appreciate your suggestions, all extremely helpful.

Why not ask the entity itself? It is hyperintelligent, it should be able to provide the best answer to the protagonists. And for that answer we would need more information on the entities inner workings.

They might worship the superior being.

Questions about character/organizational choices and motivations are off-topic. You can take any solution you find appealing and successfully write it into your story. Per the [help/on-topic], we help you build your world, not tell your story.

I suggest reading The Black Cloud by Fred Hoyle for one nice example of how we could interact with a being far in excess of our intelligence.

There are several ideas on what "intelligence" means floating around in the world today. At one end of the spectrum, you have intelligence-as-an-oracle. These can answer questions, even difficult, multi-part questions. But in between answering questions, it's completely idle. No inner mental landscape. Never any goals or ambitions. If this sort of intelligence is dangerous, it is only so because you'll have whackjobs out there asking it how to build vacuum decay doomsday devices.
At the other end of the spectrum, you have full-on malevolently evil disembodied (in)human consciousnesses, Cthulhuean entities, and so forth. All with 1 zillion IQs. And they're always scheming. If it can be called scheming when what they attempt will succeed without any risk of failure, even with the good guys trying to thwart them. Especially with the good guys trying to thwart them.
On the previous end of the scale, some jackass billionaire builds a subscription portal to it that costs you a little too much, maybe just a few dollars more than you can afford given its utility. The jackass government locks it down so no one can ask it how to politick strategically to eliminate DEI in society, but somehow screws up and lets terrorists ask it how to build practical matter/antimatter bombs.
On this end of the scale though, if it wants to talk to you, it will. You don't have to worry about the details, if you're doing it wrong it will let you know. And if it doesn't want to talk to you, is there any reason that you think it would allow you to become aware that it exists, or to have even one inkling of its nature? It's smarter than you, it's smarter than Gottfried, it's smarter than everyone put together times one million. If it needs you to do something because (somehow) it can't, then you'll end up doing that something and believe you had your own reasons to do that. It doesn't even necessarily have to be evil in the religious sense, but this probably can't matter in regards to human... it is so vastly beyond anything we can imagine or understand that its actions and reasoning can't be fathomed. Maybe it wipes out our planet (evil right?), but in some way we'll never know this was for the "greater good" 192 septillion years from now. Would that be any consolation at all?
For the purposes of your story, you may actually need to tone down the hyperintelligence a bit. I think what you want is a weakly superhuman intelligence. Otherwise the only fitting conclusion to your story is the inevitable smiting.

"It doesn't even necessarily have to be evil in the religious sense, but this probably can't matter in regards to human." The AI doesn't hate you. You're just made of atoms that it would rather be made into something else.

Shut up and listen.
If they're smarter than you in every area, they can probably come up with the best protocol themselves. Just tell them what you're having trouble with and let them take the lead. You might not even have to do that, if they've already figured out what your solution is before you were able to put the problem into words.

This is sort of the correct answer. A superintelligence, by definition, would know all the answers as soon as the problems come up (otherwise, it wouldn’t be so super, would it?). It would clearly be able to tell that it needs to do $x$, $y$, $z$ to effectively communicate with us right away, and if it wants to, it would then execute those things in whatever order is required.

This is even the answer when talking with regular intelligence humans.

I think you are looking at the problem from the wrong direction, though it is arguably correct from the point of view of the human characters, in that they are not used to interact with someone way smarter than them.
The problem you are having can be compared to how a pet, let's say a dog or a cat, can learn to interact with its master. It's not a pet's problem, it's a master's problem, to find a way to have their commands understood by the receiver.
Proper communication is usually achieved by repetition and reward/punishment, until the desired behavior is obtained. I hope your HE has enough treats with HEt.

Not really the same problem though is it, dogs and cats don't actually understand or have a language you can communicate even the simplest instructions or information to them with and thus need repetitive training to achieve the same response to the same stimuli (normally a spoken word, that they still will never understand as a word with meaning outside of that specific scripted interaction), while people don't because they know what the words mean, OP has claimed a "problem" that just doesn't exist, particularly as he has already specified they can communicate through ordinary latin.

You're dealing with a creature that is not human, it may originally derive from human inputs, or it may be later generation, AI written by earlier AI, and thus extremely removed from any direct human inputs. With that in mind the KISS principle applies in all early interactions, you have to build an understanding of each other. You actually have to build a language that you and the alien, I mean super intelligence, can use to communicate effectively with each other, then build up an understanding of each other before you can get into the big stuff.
That assumes that you are asking big philosophical questions. If you're all about the math then you should already have a medium of communication and the questions are already simple, in terms of describing the issue and understanding the results linguistically.

"You actually have to build a language that you and the alien .. can use to communicate" .. He's already done that, they're using latin .. so you've clearly not answered his question, just repeated back to him the step he's already completed  whatever his problem is (which he's not made clear, having stated it's one thing and then proved it's not that by detailing how they communicate .. it seems he's actually asking for someone to progress the story for him if anything? [shrugs] so should be closed) it's not the one you give a solution for.

@Pelinore Does "Yeah-Nah" mean yes or no? Just because you've agreed on a vocabulary list doesn't mean that you have a shared language that means the same to both parties using it.

You wouldn't meet it. As in, you do not get in person contact, visits or emisserys who have that. What you get is a subset of the population influenced by ideas of the super-intelligence, forming a amalgamation of groups, cults and aligned companys, who directly or indirectly benefit from the super-intelligences existence and forward its goals. Often without even knowing what the goal are- just bring that phone to market.
If a super-intelligence is really clever- it just never appears on the screen. It comes and goes as it pleases, hidden behind exchangeable faces, just felt as force swirling the water and by the turmoil it causes. People act for it - and never realize it, because that moment never appears, where you can reflect upon what your actions did for you and what they did for others. For a puppet in thrall of super-intelligence, the strings are never visible, all there is is emotions, rage, fear, hope, groups fighting against one another and somehow, nobody of those groups ever winning it big, even in triumph.
